# Without having a pressure regulator or gauge, how would we determine what psi to set our new expansion tank to?

Tags: water-heater

Without having a pressure regulator or gauge, how would we determine what psi to set our new expansion tank to? We just replaced the tank and hot water heater.Before replacing them, had an ok amount of water pressure in kitchen, now other faucets are fine but have zero hot water pressure in kitchen. Any ideas??

Comment: Do you have low pressure, or low flow?

Comment: Possible duplicates: [low pressure to entire fixture](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9830/why-does-my-kitchen-faucet-have-low-pressure-after-the-water-heater-was-replaced?rq=1), [low pressure to third floor](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3563/why-is-my-third-floor-hot-water-pressure-so-low?rq=1), [strange water pressure after replacing expansion tank](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14812/after-installing-expansion-tank-massive-buildup-of-pressure-then-a-trickle?rq=1)